# How to upload multiple images in rails using bootstrap-fileinput?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, file-io

I am using http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input

Problem is that if I select multiple images in one go then all of them gets uploaded but if I browse one after other in multiple attempts, then on submission only last image gets uploaded.

```
 <%= f.file_field :event_files, multiple: true, "data-upload-url":'/', "data-overwrite-initial":"false", "data-show-upload":"false", class: 'file form-control' ,"data-preview-file-type":"text",  "data-allowed-file-extensions":'["jpg", "png", "gif"]'%>
```